# Как по ssh подключится к виртуальной машине?

Tags: linux, ssh, virtualbox

Виртуалка - CentOS. Работает через virtualBox.

Не могу понять как мне настроить подключение между компом и виртуалкой.

Есть другая виртуалка(устанавливал не я) , к ней я могу подключаться так:

```
   ssh -L 5432:localhost:5432 -p 13577 kalugin@127.0.0.1
```

Как мне реализавать точно так же, но на новой виртуалке?

В настройках virtualBox -> Правила проброса портов, установлено:

```
   Протокол: TCP
   Порт хоста: 13577
   Порт гостя: 22
```

Comment: Именно таким правилом проброса портов и реализовать. Всё равно не подключается что ли? Какую ошибку ssh пишет? А в виртуалке ssh-сервер вообще запущен?

Comment: @andreymal, не подключается просто. Никакой ошибки. А как узнать, запущен или нет?

Comment: «Не подключаться просто» тоже может по-разному. Зависает, ничего не делая, или молча завершается? А если `ssh -v` или `ssh -vv` попробовать и логи почитать?

Comment: Недавно занимался таким же, там далеко не локалхост нужен для подключения, у вм свой ип и необходимо подключаться иначе, помню я на стаке и нашел ответ. Если никто не даст ответ к тому времени как я прийду, то я вам отвечу. UPD: Сейчас напишу гайд.

Comment: @andreymal, Connction esstablished, key_load_public: No such file or directory ....      Зависает, ничего не делая

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Бродил по поисковику в надежде найти информацию по подключению по SSH на свой сервер Ubuntu. Установив пакет SSH и проверив его работоспособность понял что моих знаний не хватит чтобы пробросить связь между VM и моей WINDOWS системой.

В итоге я нашёл способ как это сделать но первоисточник я не сохранил, поэтому прийдётся написать всё с нуля.

Первое что необходимо сделать - настроить сам VM на проброс портов.

Открываем настройти VirtualBox:
[image]

Создаём новую сеть, даём любое название и переходим во вкладку "проброс портов":
[image]

Затем необходимо ввести следующие значения:

- Имя вашего правила (SSH).
- Протокол (TCP).
- Адрес хоста - заполнять не нужно.
- Порт хоста - ваш порт по которому будете подключаться на машину по
  SSH.
- Адрес гостя (127.0.1.1).
- Порт гостя (22) - стандартный порт для подключения по SSH.

[image]

После всех действий необходимо перейти в настройки машины (сервера) и выставить
в "тип подключения" - сетевой мост, и выбрать соответствующее устройство, в моём случае это кабельный интернет:
[image]

После всех манипуляций необходимо зайти на сам сервер, в моём случае это Ubuntu 16.04 на борту у которого установлен пакет SSH.

Переходим на сервер, авторизуемся и пишем команду: **ifconfig**
[image]
Итого получаем IP такого формата: 192.168.0.102 , это и есть необходимый IP адрес для подключения по SSH.

Подведём итог по настройке.

В пробросе портов мы ввели порт: 1337,
IP адрес сервера мы получили со значением: 192.168.0.102,
Имя пользователя можно настроить на сервере, в моём случае я отключил защиту от подключения ROOT пользователя и могу подключаться под именем root.

Теперь открываем Putty/Powershell/etc и вводим полученные значения.

[image]
После ввода получаем ответ от сервера о успешном подключении и необходимости ввести пароль.

Вот конечный результат:
[image]

Я не знаю насколько правильно я всё делал, но у меня получилось так завести SSH подключение к моему серверу и перепробовав многочисленные ответы на разных сайтах я выбрал именно этот, поэтому получится может не у каждого (смотря какие руки).

Если есть замечания или вопросы прошу отписать в комментариях.